# В чем отличие service locator от ioc-container?

Tags: java, service, inversion-of-control

Хотелось бы примеры реализации на java,  примеров реализации service locators полно, а вот ioc-containers не нашёл. Все ведет на готове реализации ioc, как правило Spring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ServiceLocator и Dependency Injection можно рассматривать как две формы паттерна IoC. Только в первом случае зависимости запрашиваются у локатора(получается некоторый global state, что не очень хорошо), а во втором контейнер сам устанавливает зависимости классу.

Есть старенькая, но очень хорошая статья от Фаулера - см. [тут](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) (ее вольный перевод есть [тут](http://yugeon-dev.blogspot.ru/2010/07/inversion-of-control-containers-and_21.html) и [тут](http://yugeon-dev.blogspot.ru/2010/07/blog-post.html)).

Еще советую почитать статью от [skipy](http://www.skipy.ru/architecture/module_design.html)

Кроме Spring-а есть и другие реализации IoC - контейнеров: [guice](https://github.com/google/guice), [weld-cdi](http://weld.cdi-spec.org),[dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/), [pico container](http://picocontainer.com/), [silkdi](http://www.silkdi.com/)